# How can I use React/Next.js to insert conditional HTML based on element ID (using Netlify forms)?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, netlify, netlify-form

Apologies if this has been answered somewhere. I've searched and troubleshot for hours to no avail.

First, I have yet to properly learn React, as it is new to me.

I only want to use it for a contact form, and I have been following [the tutorial over at FreeCodeCamp's website](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-contact-form-with-netlify-forms-and-nextjs/) to do so.

The React version of the form displays fine, but does not submit messages nor does it show the success message.

The HTML-only version of the form (part 1 of the aforementioned tutorial) submits messages fine, so I know I have the form itself set up correctly.

I also tried building the same React app under Next.js (using `npx create-next-app` instead of `npx create-react-app`) which somehow solves the problems (I don't know how), but introduces other problems.

The HTML-only version isn't what I want (long story short), but either the React or Next.js versions will work fine, if I can fix the problems of either (or both), so I need help finding the easiest solution here please.

I could be wrong but I believe Netlify forms require the `action` element, so I'd like to avoid using `onSubmit` if at all possible.

Using the [FreeCodeCamp code](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-contact-form-with-netlify-forms-and-nextjs/#part-2-adding-a-custom-netlify-form-to-a-next-js-react-app), the URL does not display `?success=true` upon submitting the form, which I assume is the main culprit (or a symptom of it) behind the issues.

It uses this code in `index.js` to display form based on an ID in an existing HTML element (necessary because I'm building the app for a static site):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Contact from './contact-form';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('contact-form'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Contact />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

On the other hand, Next.js uses this code in its `_app.js` file (which works the same as React's `index.js` as far as I can tell):

```
import '../styles/main.css'

function Contact({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default Contact
```

The issue with *Next.js* is that it, by default, is not inserting the HTML into my other HTML file based on an ID. In fact, it renders directly from the `contact-form.js` file (normally the `App.js` file but I renamed it). I didn't think this would be hard to change, so I made `_app.js` look like this:

```
import '../src/main.css' // for dev preview only
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Contact from './index';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('contact-form'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Contact />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

export default Contact
```

But *this* code fails because it cannot find "document" (I assume because it hasn't loaded yet). I looked around for solutions and couldn't understand how to implement `useEffect` but wrapping everything below `import` and above `export` with `if (typeof window !== "undefined"){}` *did* solve my issue...

And it introduced another one: Next.js now complains about an hydration failure. After a bit of reading, I mostly understand what this means, but I still have no idea how to fix it.

I don't know whether the React version or Next.js version is easier to fix. My preference is to get the React version fixed because I'll be focused on learning React in the near future, but the Next.js version seems easier to fix because it actually works, barring some annoying errors.

I realise it's better to specify which version I need help with, but I don't know if one of them is fundamentally broken over the other and thus not worth trying to fix.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a hand please.

For reference, though it's pretty much the same as in the aforementioned tutorial, here is my code that is being rendered:

```
import './main.css'; // for dev preview only
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Contact() {
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if ( window.location.search.includes('success=true') ) {
        setSuccess(true);
      }
    }, []);

  return (
<div className="contact-form">
    <h2 className="grid-item grid-header">Contact Us</h2>
    <form className="grid-item grid-form" name="contact" id="contact-form" method="POST" action="/?success=true" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-recaptcha="true" netlify-honeypot="bot-field">
        <input type="hidden" name="contact" value="contact" />
        {success && (
          <p style={{ color: 'green'}}>
            Sent successfully
          </p>
        )}
        <p id="bot-field">
            <label className="grid-form-label">Do Not Fill</label>
            <input className="grid-form-item" type="text" name="bot-field" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label className="grid-form-label" htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input className="grid-form-item" type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label className="grid-form-label" htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input className="grid-form-item" type="text" id="email" name="email" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label className="grid-form-label" htmlFor="subject">Subject</label>
            <input className="grid-form-item" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label className="grid-form-label" htmlFor="message">Message</label>
            <textarea className="grid-form-text" id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
        </p>
        <div className="captcha" data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>
        <p>
            <button className="grid-form-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

The code in the other HTML file is simply:

```
<div id="contact-form-wrapper">
</div>
```

EDIT: I found a working solution, and have added it as an answer.
Part of it was just an oversight on my part. I'm still not completely sure why the original React-only version doesn't work but I will retry it just in case.

Comment: You can't change the code in `_app` to the usual React way, Next.js has to render `<Component {...pageProps} />`. Have you tried simply using the `Contact` component inside a page in Next.js? E.g., just adding `<Contact />` in `pages/index.js`.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know Next.js at all so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing with it, but I've tried my best to follow your suggestion. I added `<Contact />` in my external HTML page, which renders it properly. The problem now is that the form doesn't work, similar to the React version (except the URL changes to show `?success=true`). I'm not sure if Jekyll does something to the JS files that is preventing it from working because it still works when tested with `npm run dev`. I also tried just using the app as built by Next.js instead of trying to insert it with `<Contact />` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try [Netlify's version](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/#form-handling-with-a-stateful-react-form) which moves the `POST` functionality into a script instead.

After a lot of trial and error, I successfully integrated the success message.
Here is my working code:

```
import React from 'react';

const encode = (data) => {
return Object.keys(data)
    .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
    .join("&");
}

class ContactForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { name: "", email: "", subject: "", message: "", success: false };
}

handleSubmit = e => {
  fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: encode({ "form-name": "contact", ...this.state })
  })
        .then(() =>
            this.setState({
                name: "",
                email: "",
                subject: "",
                message: "",
                success: true
            })
        )
    .catch(error => this.setState({ success: false }));

  e.preventDefault();
};

handleChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

render() {
    const { name, email, subject, message, success } = this.state;
    return (
            <div className="contact-form">
                <h2 className="grid-item grid-header">Contact Us</h2>
<form className="grid-item grid-form" name="contact" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} data-netlify="true" netlify-honeypot="bot-field">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
                    {success && (
                      <p style={{ color: 'green'}}>
                        Sent successfully
                      </p>
                    )}
                    <p id="bot-field">
                        <label className="grid-form-label">Do Not Fill</label>
                        <input className="grid-form-item" type="text" name="bot-field" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="grid-form-label" htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                        <input className="grid-form-item" type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} required />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="grid-form-label" htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input className="grid-form-item" type="text" name="email" value={email} onChange={this.handleChange} required />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="grid-form-label" htmlFor="subject">Subject</label>
                        <input className="grid-form-item" type="text" name="subject" value={subject} onChange={this.handleChange} required />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label className="grid-form-label" htmlFor="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea className="grid-form-text" name="message" value={message} onChange={this.handleChange} required></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <button className="grid-form-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

But there's something I glossed over in Netlify's documentation which makes this work, and that's the HTML part which is required. A Netlify form requires you to mirror the JavaScript version in the HTML document where it'll be embedded, so it can detect the fields, which is why the HTML-only version worked and the others did not.

This is the code in my `contact.html` file:

```
<form name="contact" netlify netlify-honeypot="bot-field" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="bot-field" />
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="subject" />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</form>
<div id="contact-form-wrapper">
</div>
```

Also, to clear the form on submit, each named field is set to `""` (blank value) on successful submission, because `HTMLFormElement.reset()` will also remove the success message without rewriting the code yet again.

It turns out that Netlify's captcha only works on static HTML-only forms, so you need a custom captcha implementation, else the form breaks. I've edited the code to reflect that.

You can re-add `data-netlify-recaptcha="true"` to the `form` in both JS and HTML parts, plus `<div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>` in the HTML part if you decide to implement [custom ReCAPTCHA 2](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/spam-filters/#custom-recaptcha-2).